# Count process without math formula

Tags: c, process

Count all processes from this code and print the result without using a math formula.
The result must be print just one time in the first process.
Trying to count in a variable is not enough because I will not count all the process and because a new process have new variables

```
int main()
{
      int i;
      for (i=1; i<=10; i++)
            fork();
      return (0);
}
```

The output: 1023

Comment: Math is everywhere! For example in your loop expressions.

Answer (score 1):

You may use a counter -

```
int coutn=0;
for (i=1; i<=10; i++){
   count++;
   fork();
}  
printf("%d\n" , count);
```

Comment: I need to print the number just once. I know that in this case are 1023 processes. I need to print that number without using the formula. I need to count all the processes but not in that way.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this exactly once, you'll need some sort of lock or use the process ID. Getting locks into this code can be done, but since I'm not sure what OS you are running on, I'll assume that:

1. Every process has an ID that is an `int` (a.k.a. `pid`).
2. Every process get check it's own `pid`.

Then, we do this:

```
int count=0, pid = getProcessID();
for (i=1; i<=10; i++)
{
    count++;
    fork();
}  

if (pid == getProcessID())
    printf("%d\n" , count);
```

Looking at it again, your original process could reach the print line before all the other processes, and then the result will be smaller than 1023.
You'll need to use locks...